Can't press “Add Key” in unity
I am a noob at unity, but I want to make a VR game.
When I try making a keystore or just a key, I do all the steps required:
I create a new key, I put it into a file, and then I fill out everything I need to fill.
when I'm done, I try pressing the add key button, and nothing happens.
If there is a fix for this, please tell me.
I created a new key, I put it into a file, I filled out the requirements I expected for it to actually add the key, but
nothing actually happened when I clicked “add key.”

Is the Add Key button greyed out? If so, the manual mentions something about that if that’s of any use: https://docs.unity3d.com/2022.1/Documentation/Manual/android-keystore-add-keys.html
